# Application Settings Window - QML TabView or QML StackView or QML SplitView

Tags: interaction-design, human-interface-guideline

I have been working on some app, written in `Qt` framework with heavy use of `QML` for user interface and I've came to phase, which in I have to implement Application Settings Load/Save mechanism. The underlying logic already works (`SQLITE` database, saving settings into it and loading them from it), but I now I have a dilemma - which `QML` gui element to use to display Application Settings to user: [TabView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tabview.html#details), [StackView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html#details) or [SplitView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-splitview.html#details)?
The point of all this is the fact application will run on mobile devices (smart phones, tablets) as well on standard desktop computers **with and without touchscreens**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't have to use the same views across devices. In fact it's almost always best to follow conventions on each device. If you're implementing an Android app, follow the conventions of Android application settings pages. If it's iOS, follow conventions found on iOS. There is a shortcut to find out which views to use: check the smart phone settings app pages and you'll see which views and patterns are in use.

On desktop applications the same technique can be used. Find the OS settings pages.

On web applications things are a little different since web apps should be device independent. On the web you should follow web convention which today is a mobile first approach (i.e. Responsive Design).

If you have a lot of settings on the web app, a common pattern is tab views. I don't know if it's the most common one, but users know how to use them.

Comment: so, "unified" design is a baad idea?

Comment: @KernelPanic in my book Unified Design is App centric and breaks convention on devices. Instead User centered design is the way to go. Users know their devices, but not your app. That's why Snapchat is so hard to learn.